# ARTetriCAN is a Tetris variant for Android devices. Does it require access to a color printer?

Tags: android, hardware, tetris, system-requirements

[ARTetriCAN](http://pkg.to/jp.co.hoseisd.smdlab.artetrican) is a free-and-open-source augmented-reality Tetris variant for Android devices.  You print out a target label, wrap it around a can or bottle, and use your Android device to play an augmented-reality game cylindrical Tetris-like game.

The [target label](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B83vR490CFSuOEx6cThoRmFnenc/edit) is a color PDF file.  I don't own a color printer.

Does ARTetriCAN work fine even if the target is printed in grayscale?

Comment: Have you tried black and white labels?

Comment: @Timelord64: Not yet. I might eventually.